# React editing input element that has a value

Tags: html, reactjs, input, contenteditable, html-input

i have this input:

```
  <input
    type="text"
    autoFocus
    value={post.body}
   />
```

i want the user to be able to edit the value, i tried to set **contentEditable** but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" autoFocus defaultValue={post.body}/>
```

In your code, you can not edit value.
Because you set value, so set defaultValue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set event listener on this input to capture what is changing.

Your data should be state variable defined as

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");
```

in your case the default value can be `post.body`

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(post.body);
```

and then in the input component connect all together

```
 <input
    type="text"
    value={value}
    onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
   />
```

Comment: user still won't be able to delete or change the original post content, rather only add on it, and the addition will not be shown to the user, i only can see it through console logging the state

Comment: I don't know what your `post` is and where do you store the contents. You have to handle the change on your own depending on how it is implemented. I've just wanted to show you how to set an `onChange` event listener.